# Текущий используемый модуль Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как в контроллере узнать какой текущий модуль загружается? Yii2

Answer (score 2):

```
$loadedModules = Yii::$app->getModules(true);
$loadedModulesWithApplication = Yii::$app->loadedModules;
$currentModule = Yii::$app->controller->module;
```